# Will eating lots of eggs and peanut butter, and drinking a lot of milk help bulk you?

Tags: weightlifting, diet, muscle, cardio, protein

If I eat 5 eggs a day, have 3 tablespoons of peanut butter, and 36 ounces of white fat free milk a day combined with moderate weights and cardio each day, is this healthy?

Comment: 5 eggs a day?  Did you do any research before posting the question?

Comment: 5 eggs a day is only like 350 calories.  As Aizul says, figure out your daily caloric needs and make sure your protein intake is high enough to support hypertrophy.  Also, +1 because I think this is a fair question, but I think others might like to know more about the rest of your diet/exercise, otherwise this is much too broad of a question.

Comment: This question is not very well written. Is that all you eat? What weight lifting are you doing? Are you looking to bulk up or to be healthy? The question in the title differ from the main question. Also why would anyone drink fat free milk? That's especially bad if you're aiming to bulk up.

Comment: @Daniel And how many mg of cholesterol.

Answer (score 3):

Will eating **lots** of eggs and peanut butter, and drinking a lot of milk help you bulk up?

**Yes**, however I hope that you are not just eating these for your breakfast, lunch and dinner.

If you seriously want to gain muscle mass, then consider calculating your **[TDEE](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/)** and **add 200~500 calories**(this is known caloric surplus). Next your protein intake should be **1g per lbs of bodyweight**, where as your fat intake should be around **0.5 ~ 0.6g per lbs of bodyweight** and the remaining can be used to fill up your carb intake, and your micronutrients(aka vitamins and minerals).

With that said, you may need to adjust your caloric intake accordingly since the calculation itself is a rough estimation.

Otherwise, I **don't advocate tracking down** everything you eat as your overall fitness and diet should not be tedious and boring and if you are not competing in any sort of sports / competition that requires you to make or lose weight.

Comment: Oops, my bad, meant to wrote **not just eating**. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Nice!  I've deleted my comment.  Great answer!

Comment: I'm not sure having the opinion about tracking is really that necessary (no offense intended). I track ~90% of what I eat and I don't find it tedious or boring, rather it's simply habitual now. My point being: it really depends on the person for whether or not tracking daily calorie / macro intake is boring / tedious. +1 for the rest of your advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it would. They all are great sources of protein and are healthy. However, you should include some variety in your diet, too, not solely these three foods.